# Regression analysis - two models instead of one?

Tags: regression, logistic

Hey I want to build a model which predict probability of bankruptcy. One of my independent variables is categorical and takes only two values: 1 or 0. How to decide if I should create two separate models becauase of this variable? Which tests should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally fine to have a categorical variable in your regression model. For example, consider studying the effect of education on wages. We might right a model like:

$$wage_i = \beta_0  + \beta_1\times educ_i + \beta_2\times male_i$$

Where both education and male might be categorical variables in this specification and wage might be continuous. One thing to note is that when programming this you may need to use some kind of language-specific **categorical encoding** these variables. For example in R (assuming male is binary and education has multiple levels):

```
   lm(wage~factor(educ)+male)
```

Since you are interested in predicting a probability it is useful to note this stands for linear probability models, logits, or probits. To answer your last question, this alone is not enough reason to use two models, in fact, the variation in this binary variable might even be useful in explaining the outcome variable.

Comment: But what if I have to answer the question if it is good decision to build two models insetad of one? Which measure tell me if it is better to build one model where for example `sex` is categorical variable instead of two models: one for male and other for female?

Comment: Nope, not necessarily, I just edited the answer to add this in. But essentially, having one model with a `sex` variable in it might even be useful for explaining some of the outcome variables. So this alone is not enough reason to use two models.